# Need advice about school project

Tags: hibernate, grails, ontology

I was asked to develop a middle-scale project for university this year - to be more specific, it is a traffic Report manager. I was told that i need to use SQL and Hibernate (type of application was not specified, can be web-application or not). It was also encouradge to use ontologies.

As i am already familiar with Grails, im thinking in developping that project in grails (which is run over hibernate so i think it matches the specifications).

- I will need some advices about my choice, eventually some problems i will have if i chose to do a web-application (grails) or a non-web java application. Im asking for advices because i dont wanna regret later what i should have known certain things before starting the project this way.

Thanks in advanced,

Comment: You're talking about [this ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_%28information_science%29) as opposed to [this other ontology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology)?

Comment: Is the class a Java Class, and that's why you're using Hibernate and Grails?

Comment: If you don't want to do a web-application and still use the goodness of grails use griffon http://griffon.codehaus.org/

Comment: @In silico - yes the first one

Comment: @George Stocker - no. But the requirements of the application are these ones: must use SQL, and must use hibernate

Comment: @Eduard Ok, then you could potentially use NHibernate as well (the .NET port of Hibernate); and SQL Server Express?

Comment: @George no. It is Hibernate - the java framework. And SQL (cannot be express nor MySql).

Comment: And SQL What?  SQL is a language. What database are you using?

Comment: hibernate is the framework i must use, and the database is SQL server. Sorry for not being that clear before.

Comment: So he wants you to write a Java Application against an SQL Server database?  SQL Server Express is the free version of SQL Server.  You'd be better off using .NET and using the .NET port of Hibernate (titled NHibernate) against SQL Server. Much easier that way.  What class is this for?

Comment: The project is an ending-course type project, the only specifications are that i must use Hibernate (java framework, cannot be NHibernate) and i must use SQL Server for the database (im not sure about SQLSExpress, must ask my teacher). nothing more is specified, i can chose whatever kind of application i want, web or non-web, using which languages i want). I have decided to use Grails/Groovy because i already have experience. So my only question is in the main post, last paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would double check with your professor before using Grails. Although Grails does use Hibernate if one of the requirements is to use Hibernate I would mark you down significantly for using Grails if I was the professor. Although Grails is a good framework it hides most of the details of using Hibernate. While this is normally a good thing if part of the class is to learn Hibernate hiding the details goes against the spirit of the class. Another option may be to use [Spring Ru](http://www.springsource.org/roo) This is a tool that provides many of the advantages of Grails such as scaffolding and domain class generation. It uses Pure Java with the Hibernate framework though so hides fewer of the details of Hibernate. I can’t speak to advantages or disadvantages of creating a web verses desktop application since all my java application development has been web based.

Comment: that is my tought too. I'll check with the professor and let him know what im planning to do.